# How can I draw a pipe and make it interactive

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I have built this shape (that I call pipe) that built from two circles and a path: http://jsfiddle.net/gluz/4udR2/3/embedded/result/
code:

```
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1200)
    .attr("height", 800);

var circle1 = svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 320).attr("cy", 171).attr("r", 37).style("fill", "#CDDE3A");

var shapeCoordinates = [{"x":254,"y":370},{"x":352,"y":189},{"x":284,"y":162},{"x":235,"y":363}];

var coordinatesFunction = d3.svg.line()
                          .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                          .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("linear-closed");

var lineGraph = svg.append("path")
.attr("d", coordinatesFunction(shapeCoordinates))
                            .attr("stroke", "blue")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 0)
                            .attr("fill", "#CDDE3A")
                            .style("opacity","0.2");

var circle2 = svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 245).attr("cy", 365).attr("r", 10).style("fill", "#CDDE3A").style("opacity", 0.2);
```

I would like to make it interactive. 
For starters I would like that when it appears it will be built from a small circle like the following manner but with the shadow in the first example: http://jsfiddle.net/gluz/jeRgz/embedded/result/
code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1200)
    .attr("height", 800);

var circle1 = svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 245).attr("cy", 365).attr("r", 10).style("fill", "#CDDE3A");

var circle2 = svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 245).attr("cy", 365).attr("r", 10).style("fill", "#CDDE3A").style("opacity", 0.2);

circle1.transition().duration(3000)
    .attr("cx", 320)
    .attr("cy", 171)
    .attr("r", 37)
    .style("opacity", 1.0);
```

My questions are:
1. How can I do the transition of the circle with the path object together?
2. Is there a way I could of built it as one shape?
3. How can I make the small circle to not show what beneath it, so it won't look like it is spliced in two, like in the first example?

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding 2., yes you can make it a single object my using a `path` element and giving it an appropriate `d ` attribute. This should take care of 3. and make 1. easier.

Comment: An additional tip about rendering the shape using a single `path` element: It might be considerably simpler to draw this shape orthogonally (i.e. symmetrical on the Y axis, with the centers of both circles having an x coordinate of zero) and then applying the rotation using a `transform` attribute on the path.

Comment: But how can I draw a straight line following with an arc in the path element? (as I understand, this is how I should do it in order to create one shape)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is function that draws the shape using a single `path` sting. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/G4NDy/11/) and [here a simpler](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/G4NDy/1/) version. Here's [some info](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleTangents.html) about the math, which could use some streamlining. `pt1` and `pt2` specify the centers of the small and large circles, expected to be a 2-element array, *[x,y]*. `r1` and `r2` control the radius of each circle.

You can use `transition()` to animate the path, but it's not perfect, because the arc params are interpolated linearly. The more accurate alternative is to figure out how to rebuild the path at each animation frame, by calling `pipePath()`.

```
function pipePath(pt1, r1, pt2, r2) {
  angle = Math.atan2(
    pt2[0] - pt1[0],
    pt2[1] - pt1[1]
  )
  distance = Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(pt2[0] - pt1[0], 2) + 
    Math.pow(pt2[1] - pt1[1], 2)
  )
  rDiff = r1 - r2

  if(distance+5 <= r2) { return "M0,0";}

  theta = Math.asin(rDiff/distance)

  l11 = [
    pt1[0] + r1 * Math.cos(theta-angle),
    pt1[1] + r1 * Math.sin(theta-angle)
  ]
  l12 = [
    pt2[0] + r2 * Math.cos(theta-angle),
    pt2[1] + r2 * Math.sin(theta-angle)
  ]
  l21 = [
    pt1[0] + r1 * Math.cos(-theta-angle+Math.PI),
    pt1[1] + r1 * Math.sin(-theta-angle+Math.PI)
  ]
  l22 = [
    pt2[0] + r2 * Math.cos(-theta-angle+Math.PI),
    pt2[1] + r2 * Math.sin(-theta-angle+Math.PI)
  ]
  return "M" + l12 +
    "A" + [r2,r2] + " 0,0,0 " + l22 + // swap 0,0,0 with 0,1,1 for full shape
    "L" + l21 +
    "A" + [r1,r1] + " 0,0,1 " + l11 + "z"
}
```